# joomla component save creates a new instance instead of update

Tags: joomla, components, joomla3.0

I am working on a Joomla 3.0 component built by [notwebdesign.com](http://www.notwebdesign.com/joomla-component-creator/).

In administrator, each time I try to save the data it creates a new instance of data instead of updating the data already loaded in form.

Comment: how could we help without seeing the code? it's not like you just registered here and don't know how it works...

Comment: Definitely something is missing in code, probably in the form item ID is missing. Please edit your post and provide code of your form and View.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple fix. Find the respective form xml file and in this file find the id field as below. Then, just remove the default parameter. It should look like:

```
    <field name="id"
           type="text"
           default="" // remove this
           readonly="true"
           class="readonly"
           label="JGLOBAL_FIELD_ID_LABEL"
           description="JGLOBAL_FIELD_ID_DESC"/>
```

The id (generally speaking) should not have a default value, so find any occurrences of "id" in your fields parameters. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks @Mario. Your hint worked. I had commented this field to fetch only single record. This helped me as I am continuously scratching my head from last 8-10 hours.

Comment: This also works with Joomla 4. The xml files are located in the "forms" folder within the components folder.